# Node.Js - .then no longer working as expected after regen package-lock.json

Tags: node.js

We have a NodeJS Lambda function set up to do some work between an internal API and Slack. It has been working fine until recently we regenerated `package-lock.json` file.

The code I am having trouble with is below. The Lambda logs indicate somehow since the package-lock regen, the first `.then` function keeps return `user` object as `undefined`. This causes `logRequest` to fail. But within `retrieveUser` function, it is able to get user details from the API, as I can see user details from this line of code:

```
.json(response => console.log('Retrieve User Response ' + JSON.Stringify(response)))
```

The appApi uses `wretch` to get data out of the API. Could this be something to do with the wretch version? It got updated from 1.4.2 to 1.7.2 in that package regen.

Code:

```
var appApi = wretch().url(process.env.appApiHost).options(options);
var retrieveUser = function (message, AuthorizationToken) {
    let endpoint = '/api/v1/users?format=json';
    let aRequest = app.ViewRequesterMessage(message.user.name);
    let form = app.createForm(aRequest, AuthorizationToken);
    console.log('endpoint ' + endpoint);
    return appApi
        .url(endpoint)
        .query(form)
        .get()
        .setTimeout(8000)
        .onAbort(error => console.log('Timeout for ' + endpoint + ' ' + error))
        .json(response => console.log('Retrieve User Response ' + JSON.stringify(response)))
        .catch(error => console.log('retrieveUser Error: ' + error + ' for ' + endpoint));
};

lib.retrieveSecrets(process.env.secretsArn)
    .then(function (secrets) {
        respondToSlack(slack.formatSlackMessage('Work in progress ...'), slackResponseUrl)
            .then(function () {
                let result = retrieveUser(slackMessage, secrets.AuthorizationToken);
                return result;
            })
            .then(function (user) {
                let result = logRequest(slackMessage, user.users[0].id, user.users[0].login_name, secrets.AuthorizationToken);
                return result;
            })
            .then(data => {
                //do stuff
            })
            .catch(error => {
                //do some other stuff
            });
    })
```

----------- **New Update** -----------

I can now confirm the issue is definitely caused by Wretch version. As soon as I set Wretch version back to 1.4.2 in `package.json` file, the code starts working again. Any versions above 1.4.2 just breaks the code. Given the code below didnt return what it should and appApi is a Wretch object, I suspect some lines within the section caused the problem. Is it because I used query() and get() together?

```
return appApi
            .url(endpoint)
            .query(form)
            .get()
            .setTimeout(8000)
            .onAbort(error => console.log('Timeout for ' + endpoint + ' ' + error))
            .json(response => console.log('Retrieve User Response ' + JSON.stringify(response)))
            .catch(error => console.log('retrieveUser Error: ' + error + ' for ' + endpoint));
```

Comment: Well, when you regenerated package-lock.json, you blew away the specific versions of your dependencies that you had.  If you then updated with NPM, you probably now have different versions of some dependent module that you are apparently not compatible with.  One should not just blow away package-lock.json unless you really know what you're doing.  It has more detailed version information on depdendent modules in it than package.json.